# Where do I find the sources of these feats and powers?

Tags: dnd-4e

I found a build I like, it's called [Half-Orc Shock Trooper](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/27050849/What_Is_Yours_Can_Be_Mine%3a_A_Thiefs_Handbook&post_num=10#486645241).
There is a list of feats and powers but with no description or source. Where can I find out in which book or magazine are their descriptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do to find the source of a feat is to search the [WOTC online compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/database.aspx). You have to have DDI to get the power/feat etc text. But the search helpfully lists the source for it so you can go find it in a source book.

Answer (score 3):

The D&D Compendium http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/database.aspx will show you what the source of the feat and/or power, but it unless you sign-up for the paid version, you will not get the rules text.